# Efficient joining between Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, performance, materialized-views

Looking for advice on best solution.

Oracle Database  “A”

SQL Server Database “B”

SQL Server Database “C”

SQL Server Database “D”

Query on “A” takes about 35 minutes with results of about 15K rows which will grow by 12K rows per year. Needs to be joined daily with “B” and “C” to produce database “D” which is used for reporting.

Looking for most efficient option.

1)  Database "A" query remakes a table every night.  Daily query on “D” makes all the joins.

2)  Have database "A" query remake a view every night.  Daily query on “D” makes all the joins.

3) Have a materialized view on database "A". Daily query on "D" makes all the joins

3)  Have daily query on “D” do everything

4)  Other…

Comment: How up to date does the data need to be? How often do you run the query? What are the record counts in each table? What are the _used_ record counts in each table?

Comment: I would like to run it daily, but depending on others jobs I might need to only run it weekly.  The record count in B/C/D are 15K with an additional 12K per  year.  The underlying tables resulting in the view/materialized view/table/query on Database "A" have millions of rows.

Comment: Basically if all your rows are on 'A' (I don't quite understand your comment) then the most efficient thing to do is run the query on Oracle joining to copied versions of B,C,D (which I think is you option 3). What you're doing here is called a federated query.

Comment: Database "A" contains the patientID for every patient I am interested in.  It also contain additional information about the patients. Tables B & C contain information on a subset of patients in "A". The primary key for A, B and C are the patientID. Table D is the every patient I am interested in from A, plus additional information on those patients if that information exists in B or C. Reporting has to be done from D.  A is oracle. The other three are SQL Server.

Comment: Going back to clean up old questions. For this one, Oracle Database A actually was doing most of its work across a linked oracle database.  I tuned the query across the linked server the best that I could.  The final output joining the Oracle table with the SQL tables occurs with joins and the final output done on SQL server.